# Multiple operators in one line

Tags: c++, algorithm, operators

```
vector<int> G[MAXN] ;

char isLeaf[MAXN] ;

int n,path;

for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) path -= isLeaf[i] = G[i].size() == 1 ;
```

// How the code in For loop works? I am confused of multiple operators here.

Comment: @BenVoigt `G` is an array of `vectors`.

Comment: @GillBates: Yeah just noticed, I was distracted by the bad formatting.

Comment: Please read and study *operator precedence*.  Also, the assignment operator does return a value.  The operator `==` will return a `true` or `false` value, which may be converted to an integer constant (0 for false, non-zero for true).  Evil code.  Do not copy.  Throw in trash and rewrite.

Comment: `I am not able to get this complex lines full of operators` - well, distribute the code over more lines (&statements), then. If you are using an IDE, it will offer to _format source_ code - try that. ((Assignment operators are _right-associative_.) To chime in with Thomas Matthews:  Relying on the numerical value of a comparison operator (or `!`) is a no-no. My favourite re-write (using a `conditional ? met : not_met` expression) would get mangled in a comment.))

Comment: The whole program is working.That g[i] is the array of vectors.
Finally I got the solution and i successfully debugged using that. That line means if Size of G[i] vector is 1, then 1 will be allocated to isLeaf[i] and 1 will be deducted from path,
if G[i].size not equal to 1 then 0 will be allocated to isLeaf[i] and 0 will be deducted from path.

Comment: `1 will be [assigned] to isLeaf[i]` - by _undefined behaviour_ - it might be 42, 4711, just _not zero_. "works" doesn't mean "correct". ((Not a "native speaker" (of English) myself,) I'd only use _deducted_ in a fiscal context - suggest _subtracted_ or _decremented_ (_by <decrement>_ lest 1 is implied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the statement

```
path -= isLeaf[i] = G[i].size() == 1 ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
path -= (isLeaf[i] = (G[i].size() == 1));
```

If you divide it into multiple statements for clarity, you get:

```
bool temp = (G[i].size() == 1);
isLeaf[i] = temp;
path -= isLeaf[i];
```